# Does the network link conditioner affect NSURLCache's response time?

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache

When the iOS network link conditioner is enabled, will requests cached by the shared `NSURLCache` be returned more slowly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

If you notice any slowdown that means something has been downloaded again from server, or at least there was conditional get request that checked if cached object is different on server.